# Django master custom command to manage sub custom commands

Tags: python, django

My current project contains quite a few custom commands inside an app which act as listeners from a BUS, and each of the task are blocking means they will have to run in their own processes.

```
[bus]
    consume_pay_transaction_completed
    consume_pay_transaction_declined
    consume_pay_transaction_failed
```

This makes development/testing difficult because I will have to run each command individually to test the workflow.

I am wondering how easy to write a master command and make the other ones as slaves, monitor their health and respawn them if necessary. Are there any existing utilities/libraries in Django or Python to assist me to write a command 'start_all'

```
[bus]
    consume_pay_transaction_completed
    consume_pay_transaction_declined
    consume_pay_transaction_failed
    start_all
```

Answer (score 0):

The start_all-command could be done with [call_command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code).

Monitoring health and respawning them if necessary sounds like a job for something like celery.

Comment: Thanks for the call_command link, but my custom commands are blocking and never exits,  it will not call the rest of the commands.